# Why my code works perfectly in visual studio but gives me a segmentation fault on a gcc compiler

Tags: c

I used visual studio to write code for a project and eveything was working perfeclty. When i tried to compile it on a gcc compiler it gives me a segmentation fault.

Can you help me find were this happens or at least give me a tip to find were this error happens?

Since i cant post a very big code here, here is the link if you are interested :
pastebin.com/2kheavdL

EDIT: I know it is pretty hard to understand the code, but please forgive me i am a begginer
EDIT: My guess is that the problem must be after 210 line

Comment: That is a sign of undefined behaviour on your code like accessing memory out of bounds or modifying string literals. But **I** am not going to go to another site to read your code. If the code is too large, then condense your code down to a smaller size and post a [mcve].

Comment: Now is *really* the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Lastly please check e.g. [this Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) and [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, this

```
  moves[i] = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
```

should be

```
  moves[i] = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);
```

or even better, because less error prone

```
  moves[i] = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof *(moves[i]));
```

and if it really is C (and not C++) just only:

```
  moves[i] = malloc(N * sizeof *(moves[i]));
```

Comment: Oh my....such a stupid mistake, thank you so much, i dont know why i didnt saw this mistake from the beggining